# PXE boot problem using netboot.xyz "mounting tmpfs on /cdrom failed: Invalid argument"

Tags: linux, boot, pxe, pfsense, tftp

I've set up my pfsense server with tftp to support PXE booting. I've configured it to boot the latest (as of posting) version of netboot.xyz. This works to a point, but I've tried loading a few Linux images and they all seem to die with the same error messages. Key output text includes:

```
...
mount: mounting tmpfs on /cdrom failed: Invalid argument
...
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16384)
Unable to find a live file system on the network
...
```

Screenshot:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is a tftp issue (I doubt it), a pfsense issue (I doubt it), a netboot.xyz issue (my main guess) or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! I've been working on machines with fairly small amounts of memory. In the example above, it was a VM with about 1GB of RAM. I increased it to 4GB and the PXE booting started working fine.

So I guess a take-away is that netboot.xyz could add something to their menus to warn you if your machine has a risky-tiny amount of memory.